# strange g++ compiler errors from c++ header files

Tags: linux, header, compiler-errors, g++

So I'm kind of a newbie when it comes to g++ and linux, but I'm trying to compile a C++ program that I wrote, and for whatever reason g++ is having issues with my includes, and I get literally thousands of lines of errors from C++ include files (like stdio.h, string.h, etc). I pasted a few of them below:

```
    In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:75,
             from /usr/include/root/Rtypes.h:33,
             from /usr/include/root/TObject.h:31,
             from /usr/include/root/TNamed.h:26,
             from /usr/include/root/TAxis.h:25,
             from /usr/include/root/TH1.h:25,
             from /usr/include/root/TH1F.h:25,
             from torusMC.cpp:10:
    /usr/include/libio.h: In function ‘int _IO_feof(_IO_FILE*)’:
    /usr/include/libio.h:462: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
    /usr/include/libio.h:462: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
    /usr/include/libio.h:462: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
    /usr/include/libio.h: In function ‘int _IO_ferror(_IO_FILE*)’:
    /usr/include/libio.h:463: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
    /usr/include/libio.h:463: error: ‘printf’ was not declared in this scope
    /usr/include/libio.h:463: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
```

What is really weird, is that I have used the exact same includes before for a different program in a different directory and everything (still) compiles just fine.  If I comment them all out, and the code that uses the includes, it compiles fine; if I keep the code using the includes commented out, but comment in even one of the includes I get all the errors again.

Is there something wrong with my environment that makes it fail in this one directory?

Comment: `/usr/include/root/`? What created that directory?

Comment: I installed the root data analysis software

Comment: You really need to post the code so that we can identify any potential errors. But it sounds like you have a syntax error somewhere in the code which is causing an embedded linking error. Check your code for syntax error and maybe post it here so that we can view it.

Comment: The syntax error is likely in a header. Either way, you shouldn't use the answers to comment. But I realize that you may not have the reputation to write comments.

Comment: I didn't write any of the header files though.  As far as I know, there are no errors in my code, since I can comment out the function that uses the includes and the includes themselves and everything compiles just fine.  It's only when I uncomment in the includes that this happens

Comment: I think I've traced the problem down to incompatibility between some of the header files (commenting them in one at a time with an empty main function finally reproduced the errors).  Does anyone know how to check to see if header files are compatible with eachother?

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause: you are `#include`ing *another* header before the `TH1F.h`, and in that other header, you have a missing semi-colon, e.g.

```
// some other header
struct Foo {
....
}
 ^ missing ;
```